# Can't move in pokemon go

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go, android

I keep walking in real life all the time but my character won't move from its spot sometimes its legs move but it does not bulge. What to do?  Device- Redminote3 16gb version

Comment: Does it say anything about errors on the screen? Do you have location turned on? Do you still have data left on your mobile plan? Are you moving at least over 100m from your inital location to test it?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly is a connection failure. Try restarting the app. If the problem persist, is server problem so wait until you can play fluently

Answer (score 1):

If It's a GPS problem, just try enabling your GPS. It might just be connection issues or that the servers are down.